# Cannot get the height of a div on a click event using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div with position absolute and I need its height to add that number as a padding to its parent so that it doesn't overlap the div below. I know this HTML could have been set up in a different way, but I don't have control of the html. The height of each div is different so every time a div is clicked the height has to change, but i can't get it to work.

Is this even possible?

Thanks in advance!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    $('.content').hide();

    $('.slides-wrapper').attr({
      role: 'tablist',
      'aria-multiselectable': 'false'
    });

    $('.content').attr('id', function (IDcount) {
      return 'panel-' + IDcount;
    });

    $('.content').attr('aria-labelledby', function (IDcount) {
      return 'control-panel-' + IDcount;
    });

    $('.content').attr('aria-hidden', 'true');
    $('.content').attr('role', 'tabpanel');

    $('.title').each(function (i) {

      $(this).attr('role', 'tab');

      var slideTarget = $(this).next('.content').attr('id');

      var slideLink = $('<a>', {
        'href': '#' + slideTarget,
        'role': 'button',
        'aria-expanded': 'false',
        'aria-controls': slideTarget,
        'id': 'control-' + slideTarget
      });

      $(this).wrapInner(slideLink);

    });

    $('.title a').click(function () {

      if ($(this).attr('aria-expanded') == 'false') {
        $('.title > a').attr('aria-expanded', false).removeClass('active').parent().next('.content').slideUp();
        $(this).attr('aria-expanded', true).addClass('active').parent().next('.content').slideDown().attr('aria-hidden', 'false');

        //THIS IS WHERE I ADD THE PADDING DYNAMICALLY SINCE THE CONTENT DIV IS ABSOLUTE

         $(".inner").css("padding-bottom", $(".content[aria-hidden='false']").height());
   
      } else {
        $(".inner").css("padding-bottom", "0px");
  
        $(this).attr('aria-expanded', false).removeClass('active').parent().next('.content').slideUp().attr('aria-hidden', 'true');
      }

      return false;
    }); 
});
```

```css
.slides-wrapper{
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}
.slides-wrapper .inner{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.content{
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}

.slide{
     padding:0px 30px;
}
.active{
color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slides-wrapper">
        <div class="inner">
        
            <div class="slide">
                <div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="image placeholder"></div>
                <div class="title">First Slide</div>
                <div class="content">
                    <p><strong>First slide content</strong> Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus. Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="slide">
                <div class="field field--name-field-second-panel-image field--type-image field--label-hidden field--item"> <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="image placeholder">
                </div>
                <div  class="title">Second Slide</div>
                <div class="content">
                    <p><strong>Second lside content </strong>Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus. Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus.</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="slide">
                <div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="image placeholder"></div>
                <div  class="title">Third slide</div>
                <div class="content">
                    <p><strong>Third slide content&nbsp;</strong>Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus. Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus.&nbsp;<strong>Third Panel content&nbsp;</strong>Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus. Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus.vv<strong>Third Panel content&nbsp;</strong>Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus. Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus.<strong>Third Panel content&nbsp;</strong>Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus. Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus.<strong>Third Panel content&nbsp;</strong>Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus. Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec rutrum congue leo eget malesuada. Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor volutpat.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec rutrum congue leo eget malesuada. Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor volutpat.vLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec rutrum congue leo eget malesuada. Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor volutpat.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec rutrum congue leo eget malesuada. Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor volutpat.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec rutrum congue leo eget malesuada. Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor volutpat.v
    </div>
```

Comment: Try console logging out the height, it's probably an array , you need to work with single elements not an array

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but how would I set up an array this?